# Will a ConcurrentDictionary over the HttpRuntime.Cache hurt me in the long run?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, performance

I am trying to squeeze out any little bit of perf possible, and as such I was looking at a custom ViewLocationCache.

The default one stores the lookup in the `HttpRuntime.Cache`, and if possible, I wanted to try to avoid the overhead associated there. Mainly because I have several views that call `Html.RenderPartial` in a loop.

What I thought about doing was using a `ConcurrentDictionary` instead. I have looked through the MVC source, and I can't see nor think of a reason this would be bad. I deploy to Azure, so the AppDomain is guaranteed to get reset on a deploy, and I don't need to worry about bad hits.

Am I missing something painfully obvious as to why I *shouldn't* do this?

```
//fastCache is a static ConcurrentDictionary<string, string>
public string GetViewLocation(HttpContextBase httpContext, string key)
{
    return fastCache[key];
}

public void InsertViewLocation(HttpContextBase httpContext, string key, string virtualPath)
{
    fastCache[key] = virtualPath;
}
```

Comment: Is `HttpRuntime.Cache` *really* your perf bottleneck?

Comment: Not THE bottleneck, but there is a tax with it that I am trying to avoid

Comment: I am working on fixing the other slow parts, but the above code speeds up some views by about 10ms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`HttpRuntime.Cache` gives you fine grained expiration policy that could be configured which you don't get with the concurrent dictionary. For example if your server starts running low on memory based on the priority you have defined for your items it will expire them, whereas the concurrent dictionary will continue to grow until your application blows with out of memory errors. But if you have determined that `HttpRuntime.Cache` is somehow penalizing your application performance (which would be pretty surprising) it seems a valid reason to try to find an alternative. Just don't forget that there's much more to `HttpRuntime.Cache` than a simple thread safe hashtable.

Comment: I had a feeling I was missing something obvious. Thanks